# FFT Data from Android Visualizer dependent on volume

Tags: java, android, audio-player, android-music-player

I've been struggling with this for the past hour and it's driving me nuts. I'm making a music app, and i want to have a visualizer built in. I have a MediaPlayer object, and I'm linking a Visualizer to that player's session id, but the data I get is dependent on the volume. I've tried initializing an Equalizer before and after the visualizer, and I've tried changing the audio stream to music in the activity, but nothing is working.

How can I make the visualizer not dependent on the output volume of the device?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this: `setVolumeControlStream (AudioManager. STREAM_MUSIC);` in your activity, if you have a fragment you can call it with `getActivity()`. Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried that, but it did not serm to have any effect. Also why would this work? I saw it in a few other places but there were no explanations

Comment: Tomorrow probably

Comment: @AlexandruMihaila How does setting a volume control stream allow the equalizer to work?